# Duplicate images in wordpress

Tags: images

I use wordpress for my site and have a problem with the'blog' section (here called news and events. Why is the first image duplicated - http://www.fiumanofineart.com/news-events/
I have tried to fix it but i cant...
Any help would be great, thanky you

Answer (score 0):

Its really looks like templates in your news-events section are use Featured image, and next (a same as first image) - just inserted into post body contents as Image.

I Suggest you to remove featured image ( but not to delete it from wp), in this case you will avoid using duplicated image, un till you decide how its should be used with your wordpress developer/designer.